Glowing voronoi lines texture without the usage of "distance to edge"
I have long ago attempted creating glowing lines with Chebychev voronoi pattern, but I was never able to make it work. Is there a way to make textures having such lines, with them being glowing and having adjustable thickness?
(bump used solely for pattern display purposes)

